# renderRglwidget with rgl.snapshot produces black png image

Tags: r, shiny, rgl

I am trying to save a snapshot of the widget that is being displayed in shiny using the renderRglwidget capability. The idea is to save the user orientation as a snapshot. However, the rgl.snapshot function just produces a small black box.

Is this something that is even capable with shiny and rgl?

```
output$webgl3Dalign <- renderRglwidget ({
    try(rgl.close())
    points3d(tt1, size=3, col="dimgray", box=FALSE)
    points3d(tt2, size=3, col="dodgerblue", box=FALSE)
    axes3d(c('x++', 'y++', 'z++'))
    rgl.snapshot("file.png")
    rglwidget()
})
```

Comment: Your example is very incomplete, but a likely issue is that  `rgl.snapshot` works with the `rgl` window on the host machine.  Normally in `shiny`, you use the null device, with no display on the host machine, everything is done via Javascript and HTML on the client.  You can't get a snapshot there.